# Magento - custom collection query to load the products that have the same attribute value

Tags: magento

I want to make a custom collection query to load the products that have the same custom attribute "art_nr".

I have done this :

```
$art_nr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getArt_nr();
```

to load my attribute in the current product page, and now I want to use it in my request.

Thanks for help to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic example would be something like:

```
$_artCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('art_nr', $art_nr);
```

Also note that the magic getter for 'art_nr' is simply 'getArtNr', no need for underscores!

Comment: When  make var_dump($_artCollection) I get a white page

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the correct syntax is either `getAntNr()` or `getData('ant_nr')`. Second of all what do you mean by "Use it in request?"

Comment: Thanks Max, 
I want to use it in the page media.phtml to show the thumbnails of the products that have the same "art_nr" in the place of the thumbnails of the current product.